# Add a divisor! A game

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, combinatorics, number-theory, game-theory

> Let $k$ be a positive integer. Amy and Ben are playing a game, with the number $1$ written on the whiteboard initially. Amy and Ben do the following in order, starting with Amy:
>
> Suppose the number on the whiteboard is $n$. The person who is making the turn chooses $d$ which is a divisor of $n$ and replaces the number on the whiteboard with $n+d$.
>
> The player who writes a number larger than $k$ loses. Who has a winning strategy for each $k$?

The winner can be easily determined for odd $k$, so [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers) applies for odd $k$. But for other values, you can write a program and test it out.

---

Edit: Could anyone find the person who has the winning strategy of even $k$ by mathematical proofs? The one who does it will be awarded a checkmark.

Comment: 1 is on the whiteboard initially. The number on the whiteboard is n. We then choose a divisor - which can only be 1 initially. So Amy has to write 2 on the whiteboard. Then Ben can choose between 1 and 2. Do I get this right?

Comment: @ThomasWeller, Sorry, but I was sleeping. You are correct. I posted this before I slept.

Answer (score 6):

**Partial answer: odd $k$ ([no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers))**

> Ben

has a winning strategy, namely

> always choose $d=1$ and leave an odd number on the board.

This wins because

> Amy is always faced with an odd number and is forced to choose an odd divisor, thereby turning it into an even number. Ben just turns $2r$ into $2r+1$ every time, which means the first person to exceed the odd number $k$ must be Amy.

*If computers are required for even $k$, I'll leave that for someone else. I'm no good at programming.*

General notes:

- > If you write $k$ on the board, you win. If you write $k-1$ or (for $k$ even) $k-2$ on the board, you lose.
- > If $k=2$, **Amy** wins by writing $2$.
  >  If $k=4$, **Ben** wins because Amy writes $2$.
  >  If $k=6$, **Amy** wins because Ben must write $3$ or $4$.
  >  If $k=8$, **Ben** wins by writing $3$ because Amy must write $4$ or $6$.
  >  If $k=10$, then writing $5$ or $6$ or $8$ or $9$ is a loss, so **Ben** wins by writing $4$.
  >  If $k=12$, then writing $6$ or $8$ or $9$ or $10$ is a loss, so **Ben** wins by writing $3$.

Comment: Even if you land on $k/2$ for $k$ even, you lose.

Answer (score 4):

(Not an answer but too long for a comment - computer based)

I checked all the possible games for $1 \leq k \leq 10000$ by computer. I discovered the following:

> Amy only has a winning strategy for $k=2,\,6$.

I have no idea why this is, but in case it is of some use, the following spoiler contains a table of the winning and losing positions for even $k$ between $2$ and $20$. Note that "Winning" means "If you start in this position, you have a winning strategy."

> Winning positions for k = 2:
>  1: Winning
>  2: Losing
>  Winning positions for k = 4:
>  1: Losing
>  2: Winning
>  3: Winning
>  4: Losing
>  Winning positions for k = 6:
>  1: Winning
>  2: Losing
>  3: Winning
>  4: Winning
>  5: Winning
>  6: Losing
>  Winning positions for k = 8:
>  1: Losing
>  2: Winning
>  3: Losing
>  4: Winning
>  5: Losing
>  6: Winning
>  7: Winning
>  8: Losing
>  Winning positions for k = 10:
>  1: Losing
>  2: Winning
>  3: Winning
>  4: Losing
>  5: Winning
>  6: Winning
>  7: Losing
>  8: Winning
>  9: Winning
>  10: Losing
>  Winning positions for k = 12:
>  1: Losing
>  2: Winning
>  3: Losing
>  4: Winning
>  5: Losing
>  6: Winning
>  7: Losing
>  8: Winning
>  9: Winning
>  10: Winning
>  11: Winning
>  12: Losing
>  Winning positions for k = 14:
>  1: Losing
>  2: Winning
>  3: Losing
>  4: Winning
>  5: Losing
>  6: Winning
>  7: Winning
>  8: Winning
>  9: Losing
>  10: Winning
>  11: Losing
>  12: Winning
>  13: Winning
>  14: Losing
>  Winning positions for k = 16:
>  1: Losing
>  2: Winning
>  3: Losing
>  4: Winning
>  5: Losing
>  6: Winning
>  7: Losing
>  8: Winning
>  9: Losing
>  10: Winning
>  11: Losing
>  12: Winning
>  13: Losing
>  14: Winning
>  15: Winning
>  16: Losing
>  Winning positions for k = 18:
>  1: Losing
>  2: Winning
>  3: Losing
>  4: Winning
>  5: Losing
>  6: Winning
>  7: Winning
>  8: Losing
>  9: Winning
>  10: Winning
>  11: Losing
>  12: Winning
>  13: Winning
>  14: Losing
>  15: Winning
>  16: Winning
>  17: Winning
>  18: Losing
>  Winning positions for k = 20:
>  1: Losing
>  2: Winning
>  3: Losing
>  4: Winning
>  5: Losing
>  6: Winning
>  7: Winning
>  8: Winning
>  9: Losing
>  10: Winning
>  11: Losing
>  12: Winning
>  13: Winning
>  14: Losing
>  15: Winning
>  16: Winning
>  17: Losing
>  18: Winning
>  19: Winning
>  20: Losing

Here's the code I used (in C++). It doesn't seem to want to go into a spoiler, but, of course, it's not going to tell you anything interesting unless you run it. It takes a few minutes on my computer to check up to 100000. (If you're not in the habit of running C++, you can use online compilers like [this](http://cpp.sh/). You probably can't do long computations this way, but you can have it output tables and such for smaller cases)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

std::vector<int> const& divisorsOf(int x){ //Memoized function returning divisors calculated by trial division.
    static std::vector<std::vector<int> > cache;
    if(cache.size() >= x){
        return cache[x-1];
    }
    if(x != cache.size() + 1) divisorsOf(x-1); //Compute all divisors before this.
    std::vector<int> divisorList;
    for(int i = 1; i <= x; ++i){
        if(x % i == 0) divisorList.push_back(i);
    }
    cache.push_back(std::move(divisorList));
    return cache.back();
}
void checkCase(int k){
    std::vector<bool> winPositions;
    winPositions.resize(k); //winPositions[k] will be true at the end position k+1 is winning.
    for(int p = k; p > 0; --p){ //Compute positions from the end
        bool winning = false; //A position is winning if it can move to a losing position.
        for(int divisor : divisorsOf(p)){
            if(p + divisor <= k && !winPositions[p + divisor - 1])
                winning = true;
        };
        winPositions[p - 1] = winning;
    }
    //The following lines would print the full table of winning/losing positions:
    /*std::cout << "Winning positions for k = " << k << ":\n";
     for(int p = 1; p <= k; ++p){
     std::cout <<"\t" << p << ": " << (winPositions[p-1]?"Winning":"Losing") << "\n";
     }*/
    //This outputs only whether the first player wins.
    if(winPositions[0])
        std::cout << "First player wins for k = " << k << "\n";
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int max = 100000;
    for(int i = 1; i <= max; ++i){
        checkCase(i);
    }
    std::cout << "Done. Checked up to " << max << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

---

Edit: some non-computer work. It seems like, if you forget about $k$ (assume it's larger than we touch in our logic), you can derive some interesting results from assuming "$1$ is a winning position" then just using that a position is winning if and only if it can move to a losing position. Details spoilered:

> In particular you can figure out that $2$ must be a loss, then $3, 4$ must be a win, which, since $3$ can only move to $4$ or $6$ implies that $6$ must be a loss. You can prove, of the positions $1 \leq p \leq 16$, only $p=2,\,6,\,10,\,14$ are losses and the rest are wins from this assumption (and the assumption that $k>16$). There's a smattering of further results for higher positions - most notably, it turns out that $p=22$ is a loss - but nothing as dramatic as a uniquely determined answer.
>  You would hope to derive a contradiction here, but I realized that this is not possible, because setting any position $p$ equal to $2$ mod $4$ as a loss and the rest as wins satisfies the axiom that a position is a win if and only if it has a move to a loss, since you can add $2$ to anything of the form $4n$ or $1$ to anything of the form $4n+1$, you cannot add a multiple of $4$ to a loss of the form $4n+2$, and then every number of the form $4n+3$ has a prime divisor of the form $4m+3$, so can reach something of the form $4k+2$. So I guess this method doesn't lead to a solution, but it seemed interesting enough to share.

Comment: Interesting that for even $k$, the numbers for which that player has a winning strategy are all rot13(gur cerivbhf jvaavat ahzore cyhf n fhpprffviryl vapernfvat cbjre bs gjb).

Comment: @shoover I just realized, while inspecting tables, that I made a terrible error which changes the results! (I computed the divisors of $6$ as $1,2,6$ previously... oops!) I fixed it in the answer.

Comment: To put code or other preformatted text in a spoiler block, use the ```<pre>...</pre>``` tags. You still need ```>!``` on each line.